# Require dependant secondary excel workbook to be saved and closed before primary may close using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am fairly novice to VBA and am looking for some help. I have a Dashboard that accesses a secondary file where the users enter in their information. I was wondering if there is any way that you could require the secondary workbook to be closed before you could close the original dashboard that has been launched.

As an example: on close of FPA_Opportunities_v6.xlsm if CCC_Error_Tracker.xlsm is currently active require CCC_Error_Tracker.xlsm to be closed before FPA_Opportunities_v6.xlsm can be shut down.

The file I would like to be required to be closed is located at "Supporting_Files\CCC_Error_Tracker.xlsm
The primary dashboard that the users launch is located at:\\\Opportunities_Dashboard\FPA_Opportunities_v6.xlsm.

Right now I have it set up to where it will detect if my FPA_Opportunities_v6.xlsm  Dashboard is read only because only Team Leaders should be able to make changes to this. The response to provides to the user is "No changes have been made by an authorized Captain. If changes have been made to the CCS_Error_Tracker and were prompted that your changes have been saved, you're good to go. Please close that window to save settings."

I would rather not confuse the end user if all possible. The simple solution would be to have to require that to close. Any thoughts? I feel that this could be beneficial to other users as well

```
       Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Sheets("START").Visible = xlSheetVisible
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "START" Then
ws.Visible = xlVeryHidden
End If
Next ws
CodeRetry:
     On Error GoTo Failed
        If Me.Saved = True And BackupReqd = False Then Exit Sub
    Dim sDateTime As String, sFileName As String
    With ThisWorkbook
        sDateTime = " (" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hhmm") & ").xlsm"
        sFileName = Replace(.Name, ".xlsm", sDateTime)
        .SaveCopyAs Filename:="P:\WI\Teams\Programs\J&J CCC\CHC & Skincare\Care Specialist\Alicia's Team\FPA RESULTS\Supporting_Files\FPA_FILE_BACKUPS\Opportunities_Dashboard\" & sFileName

     GoTo Passed

Failed:
 GoTo CodeRetry

 Exit Sub
Passed:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly = True Then GoTo Passed2

    GoTo Passed3

Passed2:
    If IsWorkbookOpen("P:\WI\Teams\Programs\J&J CCC\CHC & Skincare\Care Specialist\Alicia's Team\FPA RESULTS\Supporting_Files\CCC_Error_Tracker.xlsm") Then
    MsgBox "Excel has detected that your `Team Error Tracker` is still open and not been saved. The opportunities Dashboard will be closing but please remember in order to save your data you must close CCC_Error_Tracker.", vbInformation
    End If
    GoTo End1
Passed3:
ThisWorkbook.Save
MsgBox "Your data has been saved and backed-up successfully! Your backup will be stored for 72 hours before discarded to save disk space. Email chrischm@altaresources.com if you have a suggestion."
End1:
End With
End Sub
Function IsWorkbookOpen(workbookName As String)
Dim ret As Boolean
ret = False
On Error Resume Next
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name = workbookName Then
            ret = True
            GoTo EarlyExit
        End If
    Next
On Error GoTo 0
EarlyExit:
    IsWorkbookOpen = ret
End Function
```

Let me know if there is anything else that would help others. I want to be as accurate as possible. Please provide any tips thanks.

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: I have provided a sample above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way to test if a book is closed is to test if it's no longer open.

This function will check whether a workbook (specified by *name*) is open, and will return a Boolean True or False value which you can use in your code logic to check whether the workbook is still open.

For example:

```
If IsWorkbookOpen("FPA_Opportunities_v6.xlsm") Then
    MsgBox "A message box to let the user know they need to save & close first..., etc.", vbInformation
End If
```

Here is the function:

```
Function IsWorkbookOpen(workbookName as String)
Dim ret as Boolean
ret = False
On Error Resume Next
    For each wb in Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name = workbookName Then
            ret = True
            GoTo EarlyExit
        End If
    Next
On Error GoTo 0
EarlyExit:
    IsWorkbookOpen = ret
End Function
```

Make sure to put the function *outside* of the Sub, immediately after the `End Sub` would be good, or you can put it before the `Sub ...`, or you could put it in a different module if you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. So Basically if I wanted "CCC_Error_Tracker.xlsm" then I would put that in the place of your example?

Comment: Yes, of course. Better yet, if you have a variable in scope of the Dashboard module(s) or procedures, you can use the variable instead of hardcoding the filename.

Comment: I am having some difficulty with this. It's trying to say end sub and not end if? Compile error?

Comment: You're going to need to update your original question to show the code as you're currently trying to implement it. I do not think there is anything in the code (as written, in my answer) which would raise a compile error of that nature.

Comment: I put in the example of where I want it to go but I am a little confused slightly, As said, I am very new to this so I am learning as I go. I updated where I want it to play out. I still want everything around it to take place as well I want that function to only occur if what leading up to passed2 occur if that make sense.

Comment: No worries. You can't put the `Function ...` code *inside* the `Sub ... ` so that's why you're getting the compile error.  You can call the function like `If IsWorkbookOpen(...` but you can't *define* the function inside the sub.  Move that entire block of code, and put it outside the Sub. You can even put it in a different module, if you want.

Comment: Ok and then final qestion in the fuction under `If wb.Name = workbookName Then` . for workbook name would I just put the link to that location again?

Comment: Nope. You've passed the name to the function from above, in the If IsWorkbookOpen statement

Comment: What this function does is looks at all open workbooks and if it find the specific workbook is open, it returns True. Otherwise returns False, indicating that the specific wb is not open.

Comment: I have updated my code. No compile errors or anything. However excel doesnt detect it. What happens is in Non read only mode it will say saved sucessful and when in read only mode it doesnt detect and jumps to end1: and asks if I want to save. I basically after advise the user `Excel has detected that your Team Error Tracker is still open and not been saved. The opportunities Dashboard will be closing but please remember in order to save your data you must close CCC_Error_Tracker` I would like excel to just close. But it doesnt seem to even detect the ccc tracker when it's open.

Comment: @DavidZemens this code will look at all workbooks in the existing application. From the question though, I think they could be active on a second computer?

Answer (score 1):

Your current code checks only the current instance on the local machine, the file may be open in another instance, or on another computer altogther

The code below (credit [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WaitForFileClose.htm)) tests to see if the file is open on any machine.

Enter your full file path to check.

ie
`S:\Opportunities_Dashboard\FPA_Opportunities_v6.xlsm`

*test for file*

```
Sub CheckWb()
If IsFileOpen("C:\temp\checka.xlsm") Then MsgBox "File open somewhere .....", vbInformation
End Sub
```

*checking finction*

```
Private Function IsFileOpen(FileName As String) As Boolean
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' IsFileOpen
' By Chip Pearson www.cpearson.com/excel chip@cpearson.com
' This function determines whether a file is open by any program. Returns TRUE or FALSE
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim FileNum As Integer
Dim ErrNum As Integer

On Error Resume Next   ' Turn error checking off.

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' If we were passed in an empty string,
' there is no file to test so return FALSE.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
If FileName = vbNullString Then
    IsFileOpen = False
    Exit Function
End If

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' If the file doesn't exist,
' it isn't open so get out now.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
If Dir(FileName) = vbNullString Then
    IsFileOpen = False
    Exit Function
End If
''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Get a free file number.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''
FileNum = FreeFile()
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Attempt to open the file
' and lock it.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Err.Clear
Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #FileNum
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Save the error number that occurred.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
ErrNum = Err.Number
On Error GoTo 0        ' Turn error checking back on.
Close #FileNum       ' Close the file.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Check to see which error occurred.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Select Case ErrNum
    Case 0
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' No error occurred.
    ' File is NOT already open by another user.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        IsFileOpen = False

    Case 70
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Error number for "Permission Denied."
    ' File is already opened by another user.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        IsFileOpen = True

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Another error occurred. Assume the file
    ' cannot be accessed.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Case Else
        IsFileOpen = True

End Select

End Function
```